# My friend and I wish to play "Minecraft" together, I have xbox gold, he does not. How can we play together?(Without him getting Gold)

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

**"My friend and I wish to play "Minecraft" together, I have Xbox Gold, he does not. How can we play together?(Without him getting Gold)."**

*I really do not like playing traditional split screen because it is hard to see.*

We have two Xbox ones, both own minecraft, I have a gold account. Will LAN work? Or is there a way to play split screen on two different TVs?

**Thank you!**

Comment: Why is this down voted? It's a legitimate question that I believe is on topic. If you downvote please state why so the OP knows how to improve.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.

Whilst it is possible to play Minecraft on Xbox 360 or the Xbox one without Gold Membership, You **DO** need to be an Xbox Live Gold member to play multiplayer i.e Hosting your own world or joining another players world.

Answer (score 0):

Well If you have an HDMI cord plugged into your Xbox,You guys can play together on the same console but other wise there is no way. 
Sorry :(